# How to use a single catch block for both TestNG assertion errors and RunTime exceptions

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I will try to give as much information as possible.
I'm using TestNG framework with Java.+Selenium
Below are 2 custom methods i have written.

```
// Checks if a WebElement is present on the screen
public boolean isElementPresent(WebElement element) {
    try {
        element.isDisplayed();
        return true;
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        return false;`
    }
}


// Used to click on the desired element
public void clickWebElement(WebElement element) {
    isElementPresent(element);
    element.click();
}


protected void enterDataintoField(WebElement element,String fieldData) {
    isElementPresent(element);
    element.click();
    element.clear();
    element.sendKeys(fieldData);    
}
```

Now assume there is a link say Login. Clicking on Login opens a page which has 2 fields username and password.The below code is used to login.(Login, username ,password and logoutBtn are webElements)

```
  public void login(String username, String password)
 {
 try{
 clickWebElement(Login);
 //pause few seconds for page load
 enterDataintoField(username, "Adam");
 enterDataintoField(password, "mypassword");
 //pause few seconds to login
 Assert.assertTrue(isElementPresent(logoutBtn));
 }catch({**ErrorType**} e){
 //Some code here
 }
}
```

Now comes my issue. If i set the  **ErrorType** to **RuntimeException** in the above catch block then incase of any issues like say the username field is not displayed or the login button is missing, then this catch block will be able to catch the issue. BUT this catch block will not be able to catch the Assert statement above which validates whether the login was successful.

Similarly if i use **AssertionError** above then the catch block will be able to catch scenarios where the assert fails but will not be able to catch any other issues. 
Hence i need some advice on what i can do here.
I have thousands of lines of code so **i don't want to use both RuntimeException and AssertionError catch blocks everywhere**(As in 2 catch blocks. I want a single catch block)

Any other suggestion or best practice would be really appreciated.

Comment: My question isn't necessarily on this one single thing. If there is a better way to go about doing the same thing using testng don't hesitate to show it.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what it is that you do in the catch block? In test scenarios catching exceptions is usually only necessary if you want to assert the exception itself. For instance, is it the correct Exception type, is data set you need to handle the exception...

Comment: Your logic is flawed.  isElementPresent returns a boolean yet you are not acting upon that result, so if the element does not exist, it returns false from the try/catch, but since you are calling it from other methods disregards the result and continues anyway.  It should be more like if (isElementPresent(element)) element.click();

Comment: Don't do that. Catch each different thing differently, and don't catch  test Assertion errors at all. Assertion errors are `Error` types and not meant to be caught by the test itself but passed on up to the test reporting mechanism.

Comment: Elaborating a bit more . Once i do the assert like in the example Assert.assertTrue(isElementPresent(logoutBtn)); i immediately call a "pass" reporting method like this "report.pass("This step passed"); wheras in the catch block i have a "fail" reporting method like this "report.fail("This step failed"); . So if the assert condition is true it will go to the report pass and if it fails it will goto catch block where the report fail is called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what i need to do.
I wrote a custom assert method :

```
public void myAssertTrue(Boolean condition){
    try {
        Assert.assertTrue(condition);
    } catch (AssertionError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

Modified the isElementPresent Method:

```
// Checks if a WebElement is present on the screen
public void isElementPresent(WebElement element) {
    try {
        element.isDisplayed();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

With these 2 changes i can use RuntimeException catch block to catch both runtime and assetionErrors

Answer (score 1):

Your catch block only catches **Throwable** objects that extend `java.lang.Exception` and `AssertionError`  is an Error (as it extends java.lang.Error) however, If you really want to catch `AssertionError` in catch block - you need to use following catch block syntax :

`catch (AssertionError e) {
...
}`

So this means that **You can't handle both Exceptions and Errors in same catch block;** but what you can do is try and use two separate catch blocks one to handle exceptions and other one to handle Errors like below:

```
    try{

    }catch(Exception e){
      ...
    }
    catch(AssertionError e){
      ...   
    }
```

Comment: i know this is possible but as i mentioned in my initial post this is exactly what i want to avoid. Also i don't necessarily need a catch block for AssertionError. All i really want is to check a condition like Assert.assertTrue(isElementPresent(logoutBtn)); and if it fails i want to call some methods.

Comment: if you necessarily don't need handling AssertionError, you can use throws AssertionError in your method signature and rest can be handled in standalone try/catch block

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

You need to address a lot of things here as follows:

1. You have defined `isElementPresent(WebElement element)` to return `boolean` but when you are calling `isElementPresent(element);` you are not using the return `boolean` status at all. So my take will be to check the `boolean` status within a `for` loop and then proceed for `element.click();`
2. The implementation of `Assert.assertTrue` is incorrect here as in `Assert.assertTrue(isElementPresent(logoutBtn));`.
   `Assertions` from `TestNG` are designed to validate the `@Test` results. These results are the information to you and your organization which you may want to keep track. Never write `Assertions` with in `try` block only to catch the Failed Assertion in `Catch` block & forcefully convert them to status `Pass`.
3. To understand the relation between `try/catch` & `Assertions` you may consider looking at this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43718882/java-testng-why-does-my-assertion-always-passes-when-written-within-try-catc).
4. In your code you are trying to `Assert` the presence of `Logout` button as `Assert.assertTrue(isElementPresent(logoutBtn));`. That should not be an Assertion. Rather you can induce an `ImplicitlyWait` or `ExplicitWait` for the `Logout` button to be clickable.
5. Now, the Answer you would be looking for is `Where and How do you implement Assertions?` Definitely the `Assertions` would be written out of `try` block. Assertions can be applied on `Page Title`, `Page Source` or any `Element` present on a page. As per best practices there are 2 ways to implement Assertions. First one, Assertions can be part of your `Test` Class. Second one, as per PageFactory in POM, Assertions should be handled in a seperate package/class. You need to call the methods of the class which contains the Assertions.
6. In your code if you want to add any Assertion, you can add it initially when you open the intended URL and next you can add one more Assertion once you login into the Web Application validating the `Page Title`.

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Answer (score 0):

All this assertion/verification and wait related implementation supposed to provide by the underlying automation framework. You can use one of available efficient automation framework like [QAF](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf). Your implementation may look like below:

```
// Checks if a WebElement is present on the screen
element.isPresent()
// verify  WebElement is present on the screen
element.verifyPresent()
// assert  WebElement is present on the screen
element.assertPresent()

//actions and other element methods no need to wait
element.click();
```

It has also Predefined [step library](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-support/blob/master/src/com/qmetry/qaf/automation/step/CommonStep.java) that you can use. In that case your login can look like below:

```
public void login(String username, String pwd){
    //loc provided in locator file
    sendKeys(username, "username.txt.loc");
    sendKeys(text, "password.txt.loc");
    click("login.btn.loc");
}
```

IF you want to use BDD

```
When send keys 'my text' to 'username.loc' 
And send keys 'my text' to 'password.loc' 
And click on 'login.loc'
They verify 'welcome.msg.loc' is present
```

You can refer [qaf-step-by-step-tutorial](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-step-by-step-tutorial/wiki)